# updating Textview based on sensordata

Tags: android, textview, android-sensors

I'm trying to update a textview based on sensorinput - more precise pitch. I have no problem getting the sensor data, converting it to degrees and displaying it in a textview.
The problem is, that I wan't different numbers displayed, based on the pitch in degrees. I have written a if-else if statement and placed it in the onsensorchanged, but apart from the initial number it does not update.

```
     @Override


public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

  switch(event.sensor.getType()){
  case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
   for(int i =0; i < 3; i++){
    valuesAccelerometer[i] = event.values[i];
   }
   break;
  case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
   for(int i =0; i < 3; i++){
    valuesMagneticField[i] = event.values[i];
   }
   break;
  }

  boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(
       matrixR, 
       matrixI, 
       valuesAccelerometer, 
       valuesMagneticField);

  if(success){
   SensorManager.getOrientation(matrixR, matrixValues);

// Float to double
   double pitch = Math.toDegrees(matrixValues[1]);
// 1 decimal
    pitch = Math.abs(round(pitch, 0));

//set textview vinkel to degrees
  vinkel.setText(String.valueOf(pitch));

// find tubesize from edittext
  String tubesizestring = tubesize.getText().toString();



  if(tubesizestring=="1000"){

      if(pitch>=0.6){
          kwh.setText("2,69");
      }else if(pitch>=1.0){
          kwh.setText("3,47");
      }else if(pitch>=2.0){
          kwh.setText("4,90");
      }else if(pitch>=5.0){
          kwh.setText("7,75");
      }else if(pitch>=10.0){
          kwh.setText("10,96");
      }else if(pitch>=20.0){
          kwh.setText("15,50");
      }else if(pitch>=30.0){
          kwh.setText("18,99");
      }else{
          kwh.setText("more than 30 degrees");

      }
  }
  }
```

I hope it is clear what I'm trying to do. Othervise please ask

Hope somebody can point me in the right direction

Comment: Thx for both of your comments.
That was kind of obvious i guess :$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because your logic is fundamentally flawed. Let's assume the pitch is around `25`. It's greater than `0.6` and `1.0` and so on. So obviously only the first `if` statement will be seen, since the others are `else if` statements. To get it to work, change the order of the statements.

```
    if(pitch>=30.0){
      kwh.setText("18,99");
  }else if(pitch>=20.0){
      kwh.setText("15,50");
  }else if(pitch>=10.0){
      kwh.setText("10,96");
  }else if(pitch>=5.0){
      kwh.setText("7,75");
  }else if(pitch>=2.0){
      kwh.setText("4,90");
  }
else if(pitch>=1.0){
      kwh.setText("3,47");
  }
  else if(pitch>=0.6){
      kwh.setText("2,69");
  }eelse{
      kwh.setText("more than 30 degrees");
```